# Using a default log4j2 configuration file from inside the jar

Tags: java, log4j2

I placed a default log4j2 config file (log4j2.xml) in my application jar.
If the user doesn't define a own config file, I want to load my default config.

I could get a stream of the default config this way:

```
InputStream defaultConfigStream = MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j2.xml");
```

But that won't help me, because following code takes a full path to the config file to check its existance and to load it.

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", file.toUri().toURL().toString());
```

How can I accomplish that? I don't want to hardcode my default config settings, like [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_from_code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, it's pretty simple. Like described in the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) (point 7), Log4j2 will automatically look for a log4j2.xml on the classpath.
So if the user doesn't define a own config file, I don't call any method to load my default config.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DomConfigurator, see: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html, you can parse the XML and feed it to the configurator and when initializing logger it will automatically consider the configuration

Comment: The DomConfigurator isn't available in log4j**2** anymore.